# C++: Finding all combinations of array items divisable to two groups

Tags: c++, algorithm

I believe this is more of an algorithmic question but I also want to do this in C++.
Let me illustrate the question with an example.

Suppose I have N number of objects (not programming objects), each with different weights. And I have two vehicles to carry them. The vehicles are big enough to carry all the objects by each. These two vehicles have their own mileage and different levels of fuel in the tank. And also the mileage depends on the weight it carries.

The objective is to bring these N objects as far as possible. So I need to distribute the N objects in a certain way between the two vehicles. Note that I do not need to bring them the 'same' distance, but rather as far as possible. So example, I want the two vehicles to go 5km and 6 km, rather than one going 2km and other going 7km.

I cannot think of a theoretical closed-form calculation to determine which weights to be loaded in to each vehicle. because remember that I need to carry all the N objects which is a fixed value.

So as far as I can think, I need to try all the combinations.

Could someone advice of an efficient algorithm to try all the combinations?

For example I would have the following:

```
int weights[5] = {1,4,2,7,5}; // can be more values than 5
float vehicelONEMileage(int totalWeight);
float vehicleTWOMileage(int totalWeight);
```

How could I efficiently try all the combinations of weights[] with the two functions?

Thw two functions can be assumed as linear functions. I.e. the return value of the two mileage functions are linear functions with  (different) negative slopes and (different) offsets.

So what I need to find is something like:

```
MAX(MIN(vehicleONEMileage(x), vehicleTWOMileage(sum(weights) - x)));
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't specify how the fuel calculation works how can we answer the question

Comment: Actually you do not need to know how the fuel calculation works. What I need to do is to get the values returned by the two functions to get close and further as possible. For that we need to try different combination of sums of weights.

Comment: You are assuming a particular solution. If you tell how the fuel calc works, we can suggest other solutions.

Comment: @madu 99% percent of CS problems can be solved more efficiently than trying every possibility, you assuming that we do not need to know the formula is only hurting yourself

Comment: Thank you for the comments. You can assume the fuel function is a linearly decreasing function. The two functions (vehicleONEMIleage and vehicleTWOMileage) will have different (negative) slopes and different offsets. I'm sorry now I realize that this information can actually help.

Comment: Well if it is really linear, then the most efficient would be to only use the first and last element of your array (as its linear, the rest should be on the x/y according to the linear func - aka draw those two samples on your coordinate system and simply strike a line trhough them ). ( even the first two would work, I just suggested first/last as they exist in std::array as front and back functs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This should be on the cs or the math site.
- Simplification: Instead of an array of objects, let's say we can distribute weight linearly.

The function we want to optimize is the minimum of both travel distances. Finding the maximum of the minimum is the same as finding the maximum of the product (Without proof. But to see this, think of the relationship between perimeter and area of rectangles. The rectangle with the biggest area given a perimeter is a square, which also happens to have the largest minimum side length).

In the following, we will scale the sum of all weights to `1`. So, a distribution like `(0.7, 0.3)` means that 70% of all weights is loaded on vehicle 1. Let's call the load of vehicle 1 `x` and the load of vehicle `1-x`.

Given the two linear functions `f = a x + b` and `g = c x + d`, where `f` is the mileage of vehicle 1 when loaded with weight `x`, and `g` the same for vehicle 2, we want to maximize

```
(a*x+b)*(c*(1-x)+d)
```

Let's ask Wolfram Alpha to do the hard work for us: www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+%28%28a*x%2Bb%29*%28c*%281-x%29%2Bd%29%29

It tells us that there is an extremum at

```
x_opt = (a * c + a * d - b * c) / (2 * a * c)
```

That's all you need to solve your problem efficiently.

The complete algorithm:

- find `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`

  `b = vehicleONEMileage(0)`

  `a = (vehicleONEMileage(1) - b) * sum_of_all_weights`

  same for `c` and `d`
- calculate `x_opt` as above.

  - if `x_opt < 0`, load all weight onto vehicle 2
  - if `x_opt > 1`, load all weight onto vehicle 1
  - else, try to load `tgt_load = x_opt*sum_of_all_weights` onto vehicle 1, the rest onto vehicle 2.
- The rest is a knapsack problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem

  How to apply this? Use the dynamic programming algorithm described there twice.

  - for maximizing a load up to `tgt_load`
  - for maximizing a load up to (`sum_of_all_weights - tgt_load`)
- The first one, if loaded onto vehicle one, gives you a distribution with slightly less then expected on vehicle one.
- The second one, if loaded onto vehicle two, gives you a distribution with slightly more than expected on vehicle two.
- One of those is the best solution. Compare them and use the better one.

I leave the C++ part to you. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. I'd really want to know the proof for "maximum of the minimum is the same as finding the maximum of the product".

Comment: Actually it turns out to be slightly wrong (sorry!). But a correct solution is much easier than that: Just make sure both trucks go the same distance, because if one is left behind then surely it is overloaded! `ax+b = c(1-x)+d`, giving `x_opt = (-b + c + d) / (a+c)` The rest as above. Only that you also need to check for corner cases: If `x = 0` or `x = 1` gives a better result. Maybe I get to overhaul the answer later.

Comment: Thanks Mike. You are right. Thanks for coming up with the idea of normalizing the weight distribution. That is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following solution:

The total number of combinations is 2^(number of weights). Using a bit logic we can loop through the all combinations and calculate maxDistance. Bits in the combination value show which weight goes to which vehicle.

Note that algorithm complexity is exponential and `int` has a limited number of bits!

```
float maxDistance = 0.f;

for (int combination = 0; combination < (1 << ARRAYSIZE(weights)); ++combination)
{
    int weightForVehicleONE = 0;
    int weightForVehicleTWO = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(weights); ++i)
    {
        if (combination & (1 << i)) // bit is set to 1 and goes to vechicleTWO
        {
            weightForVehicleTWO += weights[i];
        }
        else // bit is set to 0 and goes to vechicleONE
        {
            weightForVehicleONE += weights[i];
        }
    }

    maxDistance = max(maxDistance, min(vehicelONEMileage(weightForVehicleONE), vehicleTWOMileage(weightForVehicleTWO)));
}
```

Comment: Sergius thank you very much for the algo. I'm not sure why you said combinations are 2^(number of weights). Don't we have to check each k-combination, where 0<=k<=(num weights)?

Comment: 2 is a number of vehicles, so in general there are (number of vehicles)^(number of weights) combinations. Imaging that you have only 2 weights, then all possible combinations would be: {[], [1,2]}, {[1], [2]}, {[2], [1]}, {[1,2], []} that is 2^2. If you have 3 weights - the combinations number increases to 2^3. Unfortunately I haven't find a good article on wikipedia about this part of combinatorics.

Comment: Thank you Sergius. I'm gonna try see if sum of all k-combinations come to that result.